# Sync Filter Between 2 Matrix in Different Page or Bookmark

Tags: powerbi

I have 2 matrix in each page or bookmark. Example matrix1 in page1 and matrix2 in page2. When I select any particular value in matrix1, I want corresponding filter to be applied in matrix2. When I keep both matrix1 and matrix2 in same page, filter works as expected. But as soon I move the matrix to different page or bookmark, no effect of filter. Can you please help me if I am missing any setting here.

As soon I move the matrix to another page, this coordination fails.

Any help here would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can only [sync slicers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-slicers) in Power BI, you can't sync the visuals across the report tabs. So for example you select one value on a visual and switch to another or the same visual, report, it will not retain the selection you had. Same with bookmarks, you'll have to update the bookmark before using it to navigate to the other page.

You might be able to use drill through to sort of get part of the way. In this example I have a basic dataset in a matrix visual:

[image: Page 1]

On another tab (page 3), I've set up drill through on my date and type columns

[image: Drill through]

So if I drill through to the next page using the cell 'Type 4' and '04 January 2021'

[image]

you get on the copy of the matrix:

[image: Drilled through example]

It does filter out the other options but is the only sort of way of doing this.